# css trouble with centering a horizontal unordered list

Tags: css, centering

I have had trouble centering the unordered list I am using for my navigation. I have looked at other advice and tried to fix it so now my code is a hot mess. I cannot figure out for the life of me what is going wrong. All the solutions I have tried still do not center the list in the window. adding the overflow:visable stretch it out but not 100% and it does not expand when the window grows.

```
#navbar {
position: fixed;
top:-17px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

```
#navbar ul > li {
display: inline-block; 
float: none;
color:white;
font-size: 14px;
margin-right: 35px;
margin-left: 35px;
padding: .2em 1em;
overflow:visible;
```

}

Comment: post your html structure

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/talymo/6FGbw/

```
#navbar {
    position:fixed;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

    #navbar li{
        padding:10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    <ul id="navbar">
        <li>Thing 1</li>
        <li>Thing 2</li>
        <li>Thing 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Of course, just remove the border. I put that in there so you can see where the element is.

Comment: yes! thank you so much! i knew it was that i had too much useless code in there but i must have not been deleting the correct things.

Comment: Please select mine as your answer so I can get some points :)

Comment: i am assuming that is just making the check mark green? cause if so... done! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

what if you add this to your code:

```
text-align: center
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to put the list inside a div and add the style `text-align:center;` to the div.

Afterwards just remove the `position:fixed;` style from `#navbar`.

*or you could wrap the list in `<center> </center>` tags.*

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#navbar ul {
text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgwxP/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your navbar has some set width you can use `text-align:center` on your `ul`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/MD6N3/1/)

```
/* Give the navbar a width */
#navbar {
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#navbar ul {
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```